# What is the effect of changing tank camo?

Tags: company-of-heroes-2

Is there any effect of changing tanks' camo, beyond obviously their visual appearance. Are they harder to spot and hit when using winter camo?

Comment: Of course they are harder to spot if you alter your camo to the environment.

Comment: @Menno: of course I mean the gameplay mechanics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vehicle camo is purely cosmetic. There are no associated bonus with the type of camo your vehicles use.  The design was for cosmetic customization.

The only battlefield affects would be your opponents might recognize the best players skins and target his vehicles first.